# PyMQI for windows build & install

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I need PyMQI on my windows 86x. 
I try to build setup.py with msvc as compiler 
But when i try to do it I get the following errors:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\pymqi-1.5.4>python setup.py build client
Building PyMQI client 32bits
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pymqi.pymqe' extension
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD
 /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYQMI_SERVERBUILD=0 "-Ic:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include" -IC:\Python27\include -IC
:\Python27\PC /Tcpymqi/pymqe.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pymqi/pymqe.obj
pymqe.c
pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2275: 'MQCSP' : illegal use of this type as an expression
        c:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include\cmqc.h(4001) : see declaration of 'MQCSP'
pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'csp'
pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
pymqi/pymqe.c(247) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(247) : error C2224: left of '.AuthenticationType' must have struct/union type
pymqi/pymqe.c(248) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(248) : error C2224: left of '.CSPUserIdPtr' must have struct/union type
pymqi/pymqe.c(249) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(249) : error C2224: left of '.CSPUserIdLength' must have struct/union type
pymqi/pymqe.c(250) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(250) : error C2224: left of '.CSPPasswordPtr' must have struct/union type
pymqi/pymqe.c(251) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(251) : error C2224: left of '.CSPPasswordLength' must have struct/union type
pymqi/pymqe.c(256) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
pymqi/pymqe.c(256) : warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'PMQCSP'
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bi
n\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: [Vincent](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5573130) notes that he has the same problem, running Python 2.7.9 on Windows 7 64 bits with IBM MQ client 8.0.0.4.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I am running Pythong 2.7.12 on Windows x86 with MQ v7.5.0.2. Has anybody found the solution yet ?

Comment: same issue here ... no ideea yet :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution on this page: https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/35

First in `pymqi/pymqe.c` file the declaration line

```
MQCSP csp = {MQCSP_DEFAULT};
```

should be moved to the beginning of method `pymqe_MQCONNX`, right after:

```
PyObject* user_password = NULL;
```

After doing this the build and installation succeed but `import pymqi` gives an error:

```
ImportError: No module named pymqe
```

This can be fixed by copying `pymqe.pyd` from the path `\pymqi-1.5.4\build\lib.win32-2.7\pymqi`, to `pymqi-1.5.4\pymqi`

Comment: That link gives a 404